# Swift TableView UItableviewDatasource

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Trying to implement UItableDatasource but always seeing this error]

"Few hours ago i just implemented With simple cell not custom cell"

Comment: delete the tableview and add again once and try

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

You have added that method in your code. But the return type is different, that's why the compiler throws an error. Change the return type from `TableViewCell` to `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Oh! it was an error! i dont know much about voting. How can i edit it to up?

Comment: @CricketTrends: It's okay, down-vote is casted when you find an answer is not useful. I think this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) will help you to understand the basic idea of voting.